# Multi-process debugging in VSCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running a python program that spawns sub-processes. When a new process launches, I get:

`pydev debugger: New process is launching (breakpoints won't work in the new process).
pydev debugger: To debug that process please enable 'Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging?' option in the debugger settings.`

How do I enable this option? It looks like it's a pydev option?

I'm running python 3.6 with the debugger config type set to `pythonExperimental` in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

check args in debug settings of django, use "--noreload"

```
    "args": [
        "runserver",
        //reload server everytime files changed
        "--noreload",
        "--nothreading"]
```